# Recreate the loading and opening effect as observed in this specific website

Tags: javascript, css

Website:  http://www.poigneedemainvirile.com/le-studio/

I tried to research on how to recreate the page load bar and slide as done for this website (this is observed when the home page is loaded or as a transition to another page when you click an option from the menu).
Inspect element helped me understand that they are using barba.js in some manner for the transitions, but being relatively new to the entire thing, I want to know how could I come close to recreating that effect.

Answer (score 1):

**The effect**

The effect can be easily created with a couple of `div` elements and JS. Since they are using [TweenLight by GreenSock](https://greensock.com/tweenlite), I used it here:

```js
var overlay_container = document.getElementById("overlay_container"),
    top_overlay       = document.getElementById("top_overlay"),
    middle_overlay    = document.getElementById("middle_overlay"),
    bottom_overlay    = document.getElementById("bottom_overlay");

TweenLite.to(middle_overlay, 1, {width:0, onComplete: function(){
    TweenLite.to([top_overlay, bottom_overlay], .5, {height:0, onComplete: function(){
        overlay_container.style.display = 'none';
    }});
}});
```

```css
body{ background: black; color: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 1rem; }
#overlay_container{ position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: 100; }
#overlay_container div{ position: absolute; right: 0; width: 100%; background: #fff; }
#top_overlay{ top: -2px; height: 50%; }
#middle_overlay{ top: 50%; height: 4px; margin-top: -2px; opacity: .6; }
#bottom_overlay{ bottom: -2px; height: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<h1>The best title in the world</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore a, ratione deserunt optio. Fuga necessitatibus recusandae quam cumque, modi esse autem sed quidem fugit sit expedita quasi, itaque asperiores cupiditate.</p>
<p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit facere illum autem obcaecati at. Voluptates, expedita quae perspiciatis officia nemo odio. Modi dignissimos iste ullam dolore assumenda aperiam eum officiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est fugit quia et facilis optio voluptas dolorem nemo eaque maiores dolorum doloribus dignissimos excepturi eius, accusantium in, libero ut earum repudiandae.</p>
<p>Earum fuga corporis suscipit eaque, harum minima sint. Alias assumenda, laborum unde excepturi quas rem. Nam atque doloremque quia.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore a, ratione deserunt optio. Fuga necessitatibus recusandae quam cumque, modi esse autem sed quidem fugit sit expedita quasi, itaque asperiores cupiditate.</p>

<div id="overlay_container">
    <div id="top_overlay"></div>
    <div id="middle_overlay"></div>
    <div id="bottom_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**Using it on page transitions**

You can animate stuff when the page loads, but not when you leave that page. For that reason, the site needs to use Ajax. If you are not familiar with Ajax, it means that you never switch to another page when clicking on a link. Instead, you load the content dynamically, and display it. There are plenty of tutorials online for that.

**One page, but multiple URLs?**

If you look at the address bar when clicking on links, you'll see that the URL changes, as if we visited multiple pages, but we did not. This is actually achieved using the [History JS API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History). It pushes URL states into your browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

1. Animate a div with black background color. Width 0 to 100%.
2. Animate two white divs (`width: 100%; height: 50%;`) to reveal the page content. You could animate either height, or translateY, depending on your preference.

There are a lot of ways to animate content on a website. You can use canvas, greensock, css transitions, css animations... the internet is your oyster.

Since you're new, I'd say try out [Greensock](http://greensock.com/). It's the least quirky option, and very powerful.

Once you have some code written, you can update your question, and we can help you further.